# append continuous sequence of numbers to list

Tags: python

I want to have a list of lists with sequences of numbers that are continuous

I have a sorted list of integers liek this
`[1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13,14,17,18,19,21]`

I cant seem to find a decent algorithm for this ( looked up DP, but that doesnt look like my case)

I want an output like this
`[ [1,2,3,4], [6,7], [9,10], [12,13,14], [17,18,19] , [21]`

Comment: So iterate the list and look for the breaks?

Comment: Is using numpy an option?

Comment: @yatu yes it is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a better performance you might want to try using numpy. Start by obtaining the indices where the first differences are greater than `1` using [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), and use them to split the array in several chunks with [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13,14,17,18,19,21])

np.split(a,np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a) > 1) + 1)

[array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([6, 7]),
 array([ 9, 10]),
 array([12, 13, 14]),
 array([17, 18, 19]),
 array([21])]
```

Comment: I have accepted this answer, since NP array performance is better.
But want to make a point that  @jdehesa solution is awesome and elegant as well !

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do that:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 21]
# Find sequence boundaries
splits = [i + 1 for i, (n1, n2) in enumerate(zip(nums, nums[1:])) if n1 + 1 != n2]
splits.insert(0, 0)
splits.append(len(nums))
# Make subsequences
seqs = [nums[s1:s2] for s1, s2 in zip(splits, splits[1:])]
print(seqs)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7], [9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [17, 18, 19], [21]]
```

Or if you prefer a more "traditional" for loop:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 21]
seqs = [[nums[0]]]
for n in nums[1:]:
    if n != seqs[-1][-1] + 1:
        seqs.append([n])
    else:
        seqs[-1].append(n)
print(seqs)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7], [9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [17, 18, 19], [21]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples). It uses [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group consecutive runs by taking the difference in range using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) so all increasing numbers appear in the same group.

**Demo:**

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

data = [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13,14,17,18,19,21]

result = [list(map(itemgetter(1), g)) for _, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda x: x[0] - x[1])]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7], [9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [17, 18, 19], [21]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be as efficient as numpy, but you could use reduce() from functools:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 21]

from functools import reduce

groups = reduce(lambda a,b: a+[[b]] if a[-1][-1]!=b-1 else a[:-1]+[a[-1]+[b]],nums[1:],[nums[:1]])

# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7], [9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [17, 18, 19], [21]]
```